# What is a window's shortcut equivalent command on cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, shortcuts

I am trying to debug a user report - the user is running my app (a python wx gui app) via a shortcut in windows. Although I can make a shortcut as the user (who helpfully posted [hers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD47J.png)) I am not sure this will be equivalent to her setup. So what exactly windows calls/runs when I hit a shortcut such as the one posted ? How do file associations enter into this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Command Prompt equivalent of a shortcut in one given system (not across different ones) is:

```
cd /d <Start in>
<Target>
```

Where <Start in> and <Target> are those you can observe in your screenshot. In your example, it is:

```
cd /d "C:\Bethesda Softworks\Oblivion\Mopy"
"C:\Bethesda Softworks\Oblivion\Mopy\Wyre Bash Launcher.pyw"
```

The file association system plays a direct role. In this example, the file association database is queried, so that Windows knows what app handles .pyw files.

But that's the extent to which I can answer your question without additional data.

This answer is tested on Windows 10. (I see you haven't tagged your answer for any specific version of Windows but your screenshot is from Windows 7. Let's hope things are the same there.)

Comment: Thanks - could you add some docs (it is surprisingly difficult to search for those as I only get tutorials for creating shortcuts etc). Also it's `pyw` - edit: how can I query the file association - cause that's the missing piece now ?

Comment: For this answer, I used Process Monitor instead of documentation. (Hence the word "tested".) Querying the file association is a programming task and outside the scope of this site. You'll get better answers for it in MSDN or StackOverflow.

Comment: "how can I query the file association" Run `assoc pyw` in a `cmd shell`. [assoc](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) - Display or change the association between a file extension and a fileType

Comment: @DavidPostill It doesn't work. I tried `assoc doc` and `assoc docx` but despite the fact that I have Microsoft Word installed, the command says "File association not found for extension docx".

Comment: My mistake. You need a leading `.`. Use `assoc .pyw`

Comment: @DavidPostill `assoc .doc` and `assoc .docx` now work but `assoc .mp3` does not! I tried .mp4 and .mkv too. This is disturbing. I

Comment: @FleetCommand Works for me, returns iTunes for mp3 and VLC for the others :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh! iTunes and VLC are not Windows Store apps, though.

Comment: @FleetCommand Ah. Maybe `assoc` doesn't work for store apps. I don't use Windows 10 so can't test.